# Get Scroll Event From ScrollBar Even When Value is 0 or 1.0

Tags: javafx, tableview

I would like to get notified of a scroll event in a TableView.

I have currently this:

```
    scrollBar = (ScrollBar) tableView.lookup(".scroll-bar:vertical");
    scrollBar.valueProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
    System.err.println(newValue);
    if ((newValue != null) && ((Double) newValue == 0.0)) {
        addMoreDataTop(4);
    }
    if ((newValue != null) && ((Double) newValue == 1.0)) {
        addMoreDataBottom(4);
    }
    });
```

This works great, as long as the new value is between 0 and 1.0 (as long as the value is changing).

But I am particularly **interested in scrollEvents** "on the edge" of the list, that means **when the scroll value is already 0 or 1.0**.

The valueProperty does not change anymore, so the listeners are not notified. But the scroll (intention) is happening anyways. Can I get notified about such scroll events, that do not change the scroll of the list/ table?

Comment: What event are you expecting? If the scroll value is already `1.0`, it cannot increase further. Are you trying to capture clicks on the scrollbar's arrows? Or still want to capture the user scrolling the mouse wheel even though it's already at a max value?

Comment: Exactly. Anything like this.

Comment: You could try listening for [`ScrollEvent`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/input/ScrollEvent.html)s on the `TableView`.

Answer (score 2):

Based on Slaw's comment, I came up with this:

```
tableView.setOnScroll(e -> {
    if (e.getDeltaY() > 0) {
    fillAtTop();
    } else if (e.getDeltaY() < 0) {
    fillAtBottom();
    }
});
```

This works just as intended, since the tableView's scrollbar will consume scroll events that change the 'scroll-state' of the table.

The registered listener will only be called, when the scrollBar does not change (anymore).

I use this to lazily-load the table content when the user scrolls to the beginning or end of the table.

Here is an extracted MWE:

```
public class MainApp extends Application {

    final AtomicInteger cnt = new AtomicInteger(0);
    final ObservableList<String> content = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    public static void main(final String[] args) {

    launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(final Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    preFillContent();
    final TableView<String> tableView = new TableView<>();
    final TableColumn<String, String> c1 = new TableColumn<>("C1");
    c1.setCellValueFactory(e -> new ReadOnlyObjectWrapper<>(e.getValue().toString()));
    tableView.getColumns().add(c1);
    tableView.setItems(content);
    tableView.setOnScroll(e -> {   
    if (e.getDeltaY() > 0) {
    fillAtTop();
    } else if (e.getDeltaY() < 0) {
    fillAtBottom();
    }
    });
    final StackPane root = new StackPane();
    root.getChildren().add(tableView);
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 250));
    primaryStage.show();
    }

    private void preFillContent() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        content.add("element " + cnt.incrementAndGet());
    }
    }

    private void fillAtBottom() {
    content.add("element " + cnt.incrementAndGet());
    }

    private void fillAtTop() {
    content.add(0, "element " + cnt.incrementAndGet());
    }
}
```

Comment: hmm .. doesn't work for me (fx11), anything special in your context?

Comment: Not that I knew of.. (Oracle Java8) I will create an MWE to illustrate lazy loading for a table.

Comment: added a mwe to the answer.

Comment: cool, thanks - had been looking at the wrong event/misunderstood what you are after. This is supposed to work when scrolling is triggered via mouseWheel or touchpad or similar, right? And does work fine in fx11 as well as in fx8, my learn item of the day :)

Comment: Yes, should work for everything that scrolls the table. about fx11 I dont know, tried only fx8. Since you misunderstood, I would be happy to improve the question to make it perfectly clear ;)